# create new array with index key value JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "codeA": {
    "USD": 125.648
  },
  "codeB": {
    "USD": 654.547
  },
  "codeC": {
    "USD": 132.45
  }
}
```

I populate into new array after API calling success:

```
then(function successCallback(response) {
  var responsePrice = response.data; 
}
```

I want to populate an array like this:

```
var pricesCode = 
  pricesCode[0].code = codeA;
  pricesCode[0].currency = USD;
  pricesCode[0].price = 125.648;
```

I am using the jQuery `$.each` function

```
$.each(responsePrice, function(key, value) {
    priceCode.push({
        currency: key,
        price: value
    });
});
console.log(priceCode);
```

but the result I am getting is:

```
 priceCode[currency[0] = codeA, price[0] = USD, object undefined]
```

Can someone show me right code or similar question as asked before. Many thanks.

Comment: Your json/javascript object isn’t valid right now.  Too many `{`

Comment: What is `pricesCode` ?

Comment: I retrieved this json from web server API. pricesCode is a new array I want to populate with this json data

Comment: As said, your JSON/JS Object is invalid. Please fix this

Comment: sorry, just checked. My mistake put another {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to acheive this. Please see following.

```js
var responsePrice = {
  "codeA": {
    "USD": 125.648
  },
  "codeB": {
    "USD": 654.547
  },
  "codeC": {
    "USD": 132.45
  }
}

var pricesCode = Object.keys(responsePrice).reduce(function(acc, code) {
  var currency = Object.keys(responsePrice[code])[0];
  var obj = {
    code,
    currency,
    price: responsePrice[code][currency]
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(pricesCode[0].code);
console.log(pricesCode[0].currency);
console.log(pricesCode[0].price);
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer is definitely what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get a comlete array with the data you want:

```
let data = {
    "codeA": {
        "USD": 125.648
    },
    "codeB": {
        "USD": 654.547
    },
    "codeC": {
        "USD": 132.45
    }
};

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).map(code => {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[code]).map(x => {
      return {
        code,
        currency: x,
        price: data[code][x]
      }
    })
  }).reduce((result, arr) => result.concat(arr), [])  
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will looking on it to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are many ways to accomplish that, quickly I came up with this:

```
function gValue (obj){ return obj[Object.keys(obj)]};
function gKey (obj){ return Object.keys(obj)[0]};
var pricesCode = [];

$.each(responsePrice, function (key, obj) 
   {
        pricesCode.push({code: key, currency: gKey(obj), price:gValue(obj) });
   });
```

Please check the variables name you are using (pricesCode vs priceCode)